# What happens when a natural magnet cut in halves?

Tags: magnetic-fields, home-experiment

As I know, when a magnet is cut perpendicular to its axis of magnetization the cut ends attract to each other as they become opposite poles.

But I recently watched a video that said it only happens in artificial magnets and if you cut a natural magnet perpendicular to its axis of magnetization a pole reversal occurs and the cut ends repel each other. Is this true?

Comment: Which video? It might just be wrong.

Comment: It's a sinhala video by a famous lecturer in sri lanka.

Answer (score 3):

The video is wrong. naturally-occurring magnets and artificially-produced magnets behave the same way- no "pole reversal" upon breakage.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what a permanent magnet is, you should remember that the magnetic field is created by the alignment of subatomic particles. Of course, such alignment only occurs in some materials.

Normally, the magnetic dipoles of electrons are randomly aligned in space. To align them, you apply an external magnetic field. In some materials, the order is frozen after alignment (self-alignment). These are the permanent magnets.

If you break such magnets into pieces, the self-alignment does not change, you still have a macroscopic magnetic field.

But be careful. Do not drop a strong permanent magnet. It is under strong tension due to the artificial alignment and splashes around. You could get hurt.